# ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol .NET 3.5 Default

Tags: asp.net, .net

What is the default value for ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol in .NET 3.5?

I can't seem to find an answer on MSDN or other sources. I want to make sure HttpWebRequest created in a .NET 3.5 application will try TLS since Authorize.NET and other companies are disabling SSLv3 support because of the POODLE bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always test it to find out...

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol);

    Console.ReadKey(true);
}
```

Outputs:

[image]

Be careful though, because that might not be consistent across all environments. Honestly don't take the chance and just set it yourself.